# How to inject request-level context in controller method

Tags: loopbackjs

In Loopback4, how to access the request-level context in any controller and repositories (The request-level context has been available in sequence.ts file)

sequence.ts

```
async handle(context: RequestContext) {
  try {
    const { request, response } = context; //TODO: How to access this context in controllers
    const route = this.findRoute(request);
    const args = await this.parseParams(request, route);
    const result = await this.invoke(route, args);
    this.send(response, result);
  } catch (err) {
    this.reject(context, err);
  }
}
```

In try block, first line, "const { request, response } = context;", Would like to access this context variable in my controllers and repositories.

Normally in older versions Loopback2/3, I access the request-level context by below steps:

```
let LoopBackContext = require('loopback-context');
let ctx = LoopBackContext.getCurrentContext();
ctx.set('inTime', +new Date());
console.log(ctx.get('inTime'));
```

Please help me, if there is any way to access each request context in Loopback4.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution. In the controller/repository constructors, inject the context as below,

```
constructor(@inject(RestBindings.Http.REQUEST) private req: Request) {

}
meth() {
   console.log(this.req);
}
```